# Writing values to sheet after each iteration

Tags: vba, excel, bisection

This code is an iterative solver. How do I write out key values onto an Excel spreadsheet after each iteration? e.g. the iteration number, the `Xl`, `Xu`, `Xmid`, and the error of each iteration.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function srkEquation(Temperature, Pressure, aValue, bValue, Alpha, R) As Double
'The function defining the SRK equation, which will ultimately used the SolveSRK     function to return the value of molar volume or XrNew

Dim i As Integer 'The Counter
Dim Xl As Double 'The lower X bound Value
Dim Xu As Double 'The Upper X bound Value
Dim XrNew As Double 'The newest value of Xr available
Dim XrOld As Double 'The previous value of Xr calculated
Dim errorA As Double 'The error associated with each iteration
Dim errorS As Double 'The stopping criteria
errorS = 0.001 'Stopping criteria is 0.001
Xu = 0.5 'We are starting with an Upper Bound of 0.5 because the value for molar volume  will not exceed one, and will most definitely not be close to that value either
Xl = 0  'Lower bounded at zero

Do While errorA > 0.001 'While the error of the iterations is greater than the stopping  criteria then keep looping
    For i = 1 To 100 'Most likely will be able 100 iterations, could be less or even  more
        XrNew = XrOld 'declare the new value of Xr to be the old one, and then take the  midpoint of the values
        XrOld = Xl + Xu / 2
        errorA = Abs((XrNew - XrOld) / XrNew) 'Error calculation

            If solveSRK(Temperature, Pressure, aValue, bValue, Alpha, R, Xl) *   solveSRK(Temperature, Pressure, aValue, bValue, Alpha, R, XrOld) < 0 Then
                'If the function of SRK using Xl multiplied by the function of SRK  using Xu is smaller than zero, then make the midpoint Xr, your new upper bound
                Xu = XrNew
                XrNew = Xl + Xl / 2 'Calculate the new midpoint
                errorA = Abs((XrNew - XrOld) / XrNew) 'Calculate the new error
            Else
            'If the function of SRK using Xl multiplied by the function of SRK using Xu is greater than zero, then make the midpoint Xr, your new lower bound
                Xl = XrNew
                XrNew = Xl + Xl / 2 'Calculate the new midpoint
                errorA = Abs((XrNew - XrOld) / XrNew) 'Calculate the new error
            End If

    Next i
Loop
srkEquation = XrNew 'The output of the SRK equation will be the value of molar volume   or XrNew
End Function

Public Function reducedT(ByVal Temperature As Double, ByVal criticalT As Double) As  Double
'All of these variables are ByVal because they are inputted by the user, and can be    varied at any point in time to account for different temperatures and pressures
'The reduced Temperaure needed in the calculation of Alpha
'This function uses the Critical Temperatures inputted by the user, and produces a  dimensionless value


reducedT = Temperature / criticalT

End Function

Public Function valueOfA(ByVal criticalT As Double, ByVal criticalP As Double, ByVal R  As Double) As Double
'All of these variables are ByVal because they are inputted by the user, and can be    varied at any point in time to account for different temperatures and pressures or chemical   species
'The Value of A needed in the ultimate SRK equation is calculated here, using a pretty   basic equation
'This function uses the Critical Temperatures and Pressures inputted by the user

valueOfA = 0.427 * (R) ^ 2 * (criticalT) ^ 2 / criticalP

End Function

Public Function valueOfB(ByVal criticalT As Double, ByVal criticalP As Double, ByVal R  As Double) As Double
'All of these variables are ByVal because they are inputted by the user, and can be   varied at any point in time to account for different temperatures and pressures or chemical   species
'The Value of B needed in the ultimate SRK equation is calculated here, using a pretty   basic equation
'This function uses the Critical Temperatures and Pressures inputted by the user

valueOfB = 0.08664 * R * criticalT / criticalP

End Function

Public Function valueOfAlpha(ByVal Omega As Double, ByVal redT As Double) As Double
'All of these variables are ByVal because they are inputted by the user, and can be   varied at any point in time to account for different temperatures and pressures or chemical   species
'The Value of Alpha needed in the ultimate SRK equation is calculated here
'This function uses the Critical Temperatures and Omega value, and then ultimately the   reduced temperature inputted by the user to find Alpha

valueOfAlpha = (1 + (0.48508 + 1.55171 * (Omega) - 0.15613 * (Omega) ^ 2) * (1 -   ((redT) ^ (0.5)))) ^ (2)

End Function

Public Function solveSRK(ByVal Temperature As Double, ByVal Pressure As Double, ByVal   aValue As Double, ByVal bValue As Double, ByVal Alpha As Double, ByVal R As Double, ByVal   molarVolume As Double) As Double
'This function will solve the SRK equation using the user-inputted values for   temperature, pressure, the molar volume calculated by the iterative methods, as well as the    calculated a and b values
'All of these variables are ByVal because they are inputted by the user, and can be   varied at any point in time to account for different temperatures and pressures or chemical  species

solveSRK = (((R) * (Temperature)) / (molarVolume - bValue)) - (((aValue) * (Alpha)) /  (molarVolume * (molarVolume + bValue))) - Pressure
'The solveSRK function will return the ultimate solution of the values inputted into   it, this equation will be used by the iterative method to solve for the molarVolume or  XrNew

End Function
```

Comment: I see no `Xmid` in your code, so it's going to be difficult to write it out.

Answer (score 0):

Before `Next i` you could add something like this:

```
Dim vTemp As Variant
'Shove whatever it is you want to display into an array:
vTemp = Array(i, Xl, Xu, XrNew) 
'Slap array onto sheet:
Range("A1").Offset(i, 0).Resize(, UBound(v) - LBound(v) + 1).Value = vTemp
```